# Protect and format specified cells based on change in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cellrange (U4:U50) that allows you to choose between "yes" and "no". I want, for each row, format and protect the cells on the right (V4:AL4, V4:AL4, etc until V50:AL50) when relevant cell in column A changes value.

I am able to put together only a few pieces of the code based on my little knowledge: I managed to make the desired changes happen for the row 4, based on the code below.

The protect and UNprotect sub are in ThisWorkbook and they do exactly that.

```
 Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Set checkRange = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("U4:U50"))

' If the change wasn't in this range then we're done
    If checkRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

 If Range("U4").Value = "Yes" Then
        Range("V4:AL4").Select
        Call ActiveWorkbook.UNprotect_all_sheets

        With Selection
        .Locked = True
        End With
        With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
        .TintAndShade = -9.99786370433668E-02
        .PatternTintAndShade = 1
        End With

        Range("U4").Select


    ElseIf Range("U4").Value <> "Yes" Then
        Call ActiveWorkbook.UNprotect_all_sheets
        Range("V4:AL4").Select

    With Selection
        .Locked = False
        End With
        With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0


       End With


    End If
       Call ActiveWorkbook.Protect_all_sheets

End Sub
```

Next step is to make the code work for all the rows depending from the target range, so I started with this

```
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
' 21 targets column U 
c = 21

For r = 4 To 50
If Cells(r, c).Value = "Yes" Then
'here I think the process would be to unprotect the sheet, then select from (r,c+1) to (r,c+17), apply the formatting (shade and protection), go to next r and at the end protect the sheet again
```

But my problem is that I do now know how to:

1. Select the range of cells from Cells(r,c+1) to Cells(r,c+17);
2. Make the instruction relative to the right row.

Any comment on that is more than welcome!!

Thanks to all of you in advance, I hope you can understand from my explication what I need to do.

I have been looking for the answer around, maybe I have not been able to look for the right wording..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way. Generally there is no need to Select anything but I have left it in as it's not clear whether your other subs are working off a selection. You could use Resize but I can't be bothered to work out how many columns it is from V to AL.

On reflection, it's probably safe to reconfigure the first block as I have done in the second (and perhaps the unprotect should be called before the selecting in any case).

Strictly speaking the code should cater for multiple cells being changed. For this, you can change instances of `Target` to `Target(1)`.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Set checkRange = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("U4:U50"))

' If the change wasn't in this range then we're done
If checkRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
    Range(Cells(Target.Row, "V"), Cells(Target.Row, "AL")).Select
    Call ActiveWorkbook.UNprotect_all_sheets
    With Selection
        .Locked = True
        With .Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
            .TintAndShade = -9.99786370433668E-02
            .PatternTintAndShade = 1
        End With
    End With
Else
    Call ActiveWorkbook.UNprotect_all_sheets
    With Range(Cells(Target.Row, "V"), Cells(Target.Row, "AL"))
        .Locked = False
        With .Interior
            .Pattern = xlNone
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
End If

Call ActiveWorkbook.Protect_all_sheets

End Sub
```

Comment: This works great, thanks @SJR!
How should I make it happen without selecting the range?
Resize should be used with [tag:offset] to avoid selecting the target cells, isn't it?

Sorry for the very basic questions...